# Low quality papers on Arxiv

Tags: arxiv

How is it possible that people which are not in academia nor affiliated with a research institution can publish on *ArXiv*? 
I know that arxiv papers are not subjected to peer review 
but to publish there you still need credentials or to receive the authorization from people who already publish. My question therefore is the following: how is it possible that there are so many low quality publications on Arxiv? See for example [this "proof" that P ≠ NP](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1604/1604.03758.pdf).

Comment: While this paper is garbage, I think it's not so nice to provide a link to it.

Comment: There are even low quality papers in high quality peer-reviewed journals..

Comment: IMO this question answers itself in respect of the specific example when you do five minutes' web searching and discover that the author was an associate professor for ten years and already had an arxiv account then.

Answer (score 4):

Submissions do go through [a moderation process](https://arxiv.org/help/moderation) to ensure that the paper has "refereeable content"; at minimum this means that the paper must present "original or substantive research" but it does not require that the research methodology is actually sound or that the findings are actually correct.  Establishing soundness (and to a certain degree, also correctness) is the point of the full peer review process, which is something arXiv lacks by design.

In summary, the reason there are so many bad papers on arXiv is that arXiv intentionally makes it easy to post unreviewed material.  If you are doing a literature review and finding high-quality papers is important for you, you would be better off browsing or searching an *expertly curated* list of papers, such as those contained in a journal or a volume of conference proceedings.  Of course, even some bad papers can make it into such publications, though the proportion will be astronomically lower than in an (almost) free-for-all self-archiving service like arXiv.

Comment: I signed up a month or two ago on arxiv and the site told me that to publish I needed the authorization of a person who had already published on Arxiv ... I don't know if it's a restriction introduced recently or not ...

Comment: The first part of this answer is wrong, arXiv does have an endorsement system https://arxiv.org/help/endorsement

Comment: @Yamar69: Even if that's true, that's a pretty low bar to pass. As you observed, there are already a lot of low-quality papers on arXiv. Surely many contributors of such papers would happily authorize other potential contributors' requests to upload their own low-quality papers.

Comment: @Psychonaut it is a relatively low bar, but higher than what you describe. "Contributors of such papers" might not be able to endorse other people, not all authors are endorsers.

Comment: @fqq: Thanks for letting me know. I've revised the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Psychonaut yes, once there are "bad" authors, it is easy for them to authorize others of the same level.What I don't understand is where and when this chain  started. 
There must have been, at some point in the history of the archive, one or more authors who have "given" authorizations lightly.

Comment: @Yamar69 That would be an interesting new question.